# Why Comparable Interface is intialise with new Operator? though it is interface?

Tags: java, string, java-8, comparable

Below is the class and in this, I'm using a Comparable interface. How can it is initialized with `new`, though it is an interface?

```
public class PriorityQueueImpl {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Comparable[] pQueue;
    private int index;

    public PriorityQueueImpl(int capacity){
        pQueue = new Comparable[capacity];
    }

    public void insert(Comparable item ){
    if(index == pQueue.length){
        System.out.println("The priority queue is full!! can not insert.");
        return;
    }
        pQueue[index] = item;
        index++;
        System.out.println("Adding element: "+item);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Comparable remove(){
        if(index == 0){
            System.out.println("The priority queue is empty!! can not remove.");
        return null;
        }
        int maxIndex = 0;
        // find the index of the item with the highest priority
        for (int i=1; i<index; i++) {
            if (pQueue[i].compareTo (pQueue[maxIndex]) > 0) {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        Comparable result = pQueue[maxIndex];
        System.out.println("removing: "+result);
        // move the last item into the empty slot
        index--;
        pQueue[maxIndex] = pQueue[index];
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        PriorityQueueImpl pqi = new PriorityQueueImpl(5);
        pqi.insert(34);
        pqi.insert(23);
        pqi.remove();
        pqi.remove();
    }
}
```

in the above code, Comparable Array initializes with the new operator. how is this possible?

Comment: `new Name[10]` creates an (empty, full of `null`) array to hold instances of `Name` | `new Name(10)` creates an instance of `Name` (assuming it has a constructor that takes an `int`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Comparable[capacity]` is not an initialisation of`Comparable` interface but an array that can hold objects of type `Comparable`. You can refer [following section of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3)

Comment: didn't get clearly through your reference can you elaborate this more or share another reference?

Comment: @ParminderSingh The line of code such as `Comparable[] pQueue = new Comparable[capacity]` in java is *initializing an array of `Comparable`* and **not** creating an instance of `Comparable` as you might be thinking of.

Comment: @ParminderSingh A `Comparable[]` is an _array_, not a `Comparable`. When you see code such as `new Comparable[...]` that is an _array_ being created with the specified component type and length. There is no `Comparable` instance being created in that line of code. Later on one can put `Comparable` instances _in the array_.

Comment: the link is totally wrong:"Subtyping among Array Types" (and for Java 7)! [15.10.1. Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) would be more appropriate